# Many delete queries in single JDBC query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm having a problem with in my class with generating delete command:

```
    private String generateDeleteCommand() {
    StringBuilder deleteCommand = new StringBuilder();
    for (ForeignKey fk : exportedForeignKeys) {
        deleteCommand.append("DELETE FROM ").append(fk.foreignTableName)
                .append(" WHERE ").append(fk.foreignColumnName)
                .append("=:").append(fk.primaryColumnName).append(";\n");
    }
    deleteCommand.append("DELETE FROM ").append(tableName)
            .append(" WHERE ");
    for (String key : primaryKeys.keySet()) {
        deleteCommand.append(key).append("=:").append(key).append(" AND ");
    }
    deleteCommand
            .delete(deleteCommand.length() - 5, deleteCommand.length());
    deleteCommand.append(";");
    System.out.println(deleteCommand);
    return deleteCommand.toString();
}
```

The query I get is valid when using in phpmyadmin - but when I'll try to use it with jdbc executeUpdate() i get MySQLSyntaxError, i.e. for table "trasy" with two exported foreign keys query looks like:

```
DELETE FROM kursy WHERE ID_TRASY=19;
DELETE FROM przystanki WHERE ID_TRASY=19;
DELETE FROM trasy WHERE ID_TRASY=19;
```

Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your    SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM przystanki WHERE ID_TRASY=19;
DELETE FROM trasy WHERE ID_TRASY=19' at line 2
```

It doesn't matter whether there is \n between the queries or no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`.addBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29) method on `Statement` and add each `DELETE` query separately and [`.executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) them as a batch.

If using transactions, you can test the counts returned by each statement, and if anything is wrong, you can [`.rollback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback%28%29) the entire batch.

I have an open source project that shows exactly how to do this.

[SQL Construction Kit on GitHub](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/sqlck), there is an [AbstractDatabase.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/sqlck/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vertigrated/db/AbstractDatabase.java) class that has an `.executeBatch()` method that you can copy and use yourself with very little modification. It even has the code for testing each command and doing the commit/rollback.

Comment: The reason for the error is that the jdbc connection must be configured to allow this. Although your answer is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

jdbc executes **one** statement at a time, so your statements, even if are multiple seperated by \n, are in fact executed as one instruction hence the error from mysql.

Comment: That's not the reason for the error. The reason is that the jdbc connection must be configured to allow this.